# Check if array is sorted in java

Tags: java

I want to create a method that returns 0 if array not sorted
returns 1 if it is sorted in ascending order and returns -1 if its sorted in descending order

This is what I have done so far:

```
public static int isSorted(int[] intArray) {

    int end = intArray.length - 1;
    int val = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < end; i++) {

        if (intArray[0] < intArray[i]) {

            val = 1;
        }

        else if (intArray[0] > intArray[i]) {

            val = -1;
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

This returns 1 if its ascending and -1 if its descending.
But if I create a random array it does not return 0.
The question is how to check if both conditions fail, i.e.,
if its not sorted at all.

Comment: go step by step into your code for array 1 2 1 and write down value of `val` variable at every loop iteration

Comment: Just a note: In your for-loop replace `i < end` with `i <= end` since end is the length but already subtracted one

Comment: If the first two elements in an array are increasing, check that all subsequent elements are increasing too; if the first two elements are decreasing, check that all subsequent elements are decreasing too.

Comment: When you say "ascending" and "descending" order, do you actually mean that, or do you mean "non-descending" and "non-ascending"? (e.g. `1,2,3` is ascending, `1,1,2` is non-descending).

Comment: it takes just as much code to sort an array as it does to check if its sorted....so why not just sort it by default...am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two additional variables to count:

```
public static int isSorted(int[] intArray) {

    int end = intArray.length-1;
    int counterAsc = 0;
    int counterDesc = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        if(intArray[i] < intArray[i+1]){
            counterAsc++;
        }
        else if(intArray[i] > intArray[i+1]){
            counterDesc++;
        }
    }
    if(counterDesc == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(counterAsc == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is just between first element and other elements in the array.

```
val = 0;
for(int i=0;i<=end;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<end;j++){
          if(intArray[j]>intArray[j+1])
               val = 1; 

     }
   }
 return val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
public class stackoverflow {


    public static int isSorted(int[] intArray) {


    boolean sortedAsc = true;
    boolean sortedDesc = true;
    boolean sameValues=true;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length-1; i++)
    {

        if (intArray[i] > intArray[i+1]) {
            sortedAsc=false;
            sameValues=false;
        }
        if (intArray[i] < intArray[i+1]) {
            sortedDesc=false;
            sameValues=false;
        }
        }

    if(sortedAsc) result= 1;
    if(sortedDesc) result =  -1;
    if(sameValues) result = 2;

    return result;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int array[] = new int[4];
        array[0]=1;
        array[1]=2;
        array[2]=3;
        array[3]=4;

        System.out.println(isSorted(array));

    }
```